# C++ Regex always matching entire string

Tags: c++, regex

Whenever I use a regex function it matches the entire string for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string text = "This (is a) test";
    std::regex pattern("\(.+\)");
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(text, pattern, "isnt") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: isnt

Comment: Hint: In C++ strings, you need to escape your backslashes with a literal backslash. Your pattern here is equivalent to `"(.+)"`.

Comment: Or use raw string literals, like `R"(\(.+\))"`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern unfortunately is not what it seems to be. Here is the problem.
Imagine for some reason you want to match tabs in with you regex. You might try this.

```
std::regex my_regex("\t");
```

This would work, but the string your `std::regex` class has seen is `"    "`, not `"\t"`. This is because of how C++ threats escaped characters. To pass literal `"\t"`, you had to do the following.

```
std::regex my_regex("\\t");
```

So the correct syntax for your regex is.

```
std::regex pattern("\\(.+\\)");
```